# альтернатива graphics.h для linux ubuntu

Tags: c++, c, linux

Приветствую знающих.

Кто подскажет, каким образом можно вшить graphics.h в пингвина, или чем его заменить? Нужно нарисовать пару полосочек, а каким образом это сделать в g++ не знаю.

Библиотеки sdl вроде как все стоят, все команды компилятор выполняет адекватно

Гуглом пользовался, ничего внятного не нашел

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20130227070014/http://ospforum.wordpress.com/2009/09/20/2d-graphics-using-c-in-linux-graphics-h-in-linux/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cairo - для GTK+

Comment: А терминально-ориентированного ничего нет? Тут задачка сделать таблицу, в которой прописаны полученные значения

Comment: 1. управляющие последовательности и режимы терминала.
2. самая популярная для них обертка - ncurses

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<ncurses.h>
/*или curses.h тут уж на ваше усмотрение, g++ все равно заменит его на одну библиотеку
но при компилировании придется прописать*/
$g++ test.cpp -o test -lncurses #или -lcurses как вы поняли в ubuntu разницы нет
```

Comment: Да то-же примерно было и выше, но за отзыв брагодарю